# Dynamically create a click event based on an array and change format of the clicked element

Tags: javascript, arrays, addeventlistener

I have 5 div tags each with its unique class name and two of them have the same class except the second one has an extra class (i.e. ".cls2" and ".cls2.a"). I have put these classes in an array and I am trying to create a click event where the clicked element containing the class from the array will do something.

Here's my HTML code

```
<div class="cls1"></div>
<div class="cls2"></div>
<div class="cls3"></div>
<div class="cls4"></div>
<div class="cls2 a"></div>
```

Here's the javascript:

```
var classList = [".cls1",".cls2",".cls3",".cls4",".cls2.a"];
var myColors = ["red","blue","pink","green","black"];
const myVar = document.querySelectorAll(classList);

for (const myVars of myVar) {
    myVars.addEventListener('click', function () {
        for (var x = 0; x < myVar.length; x++) {
            this.style.background = "lightblue";
            myVar[x].style.background = "purple";
            myVar[x].innerHTML = myVar[x].classList;                
        }
    })
}
```

So what I am trying to do is change the element that was clicked on by changing its background color to a unique color and change all other elements to another color. In this case, the element that was clicked on will change to "lightblue" and all other elements to "purple". This works fine except I am struggling to figure out how to change the color of the clicked element with colors defined in var myColors instead of "lightblue".

I'd like to get this done in pure javascript without jquery

Comment: which color to pick up from the array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `forEach` instead, to iterate over the `colors` array, and select the `<div>` with the same index separately. Then the added listener can iterate over all divs, assigning the static color, while adding the color being iterated over to the selected div:

```js
const classList = [".cls1", ".cls2", ".cls3", ".cls4", ".cls2.a"];
const colors = ["red", "blue", "pink", "green", "black"];
const divs = document.querySelectorAll(classList.join(','));

colors.forEach((color, i) => {
  const div = divs[i];
  div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    for (const div of divs) {
      div.style.background = "purple";
    }
    div.style.background = color;
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="cls1">a</div>
<div class="cls2">b</div>
<div class="cls3">c</div>
<div class="cls4">d</div>
<div class="cls2 a">e</div>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Man I have been struggling with this all day and I finally decided to swallow up my pride and just ask for help haha. Thank you @CertainPerformance.

Answer (score 0):

There are more elegant solutions to this, like the example of CertainPerformance's answer. In case you need something close to your original idea, the following example contains the minimum changes in your logic required for it to work as you intended.

```js
var classList = [".cls1",".cls2",".cls3",".cls4",".cls2.a"];
var myColors = ["red","blue","pink","green","black"];
const myVar = document.querySelectorAll(classList);

for (const myVars of myVar) {
    myVars.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        for (var x = 0; x < myVar.length; x++) {
            myVar[x].style.background = "purple";
            myVar[x].innerHTML = myVar[x].classList;                
        }  
        let index = classList.indexOf('.' + e.target.className);\
        this.style.background = myColors[index];
    })
}
```